# "npm clean-install" ignores strict-engine check

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a project is which I want the developpers to use a specific version of node (the current LTS). According to the documentation, the `engines` property should do the trick, so I set it like so :

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=12.16.1 <13.0.0"
}
```

And works great when using `npm install` (I had to set "engine-strict=true" in the .npmrc file) :

> $ npm i
>   npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
>   npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for myApp@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=12.16.1 <13.0.0"}  (current: {"node":"11.13.0","npm":"6.7.0"})
>   npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=12.16.1 <13.0.0"}
>   npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.7.0","node":"11.13.0"}

However, the strict check is ignored when using `npm clean-install` :

> $ npm clean-install
>   npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation
>   [...]
>   added XXX packages in YYYs

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Comment: @Noitidart No solution for the versions I used at the time, but it does seem to work with Node 16 and later (I haven't tested earlier versions)

Comment: Oh nice. My problem was `npm i PKG_NAME` wasn't being blocked. Nor was the `npm un PKG_NAME`.

Comment: @Noitidart I haven't tested when isntalling a single package, but using `npm i` or `npm ci`, the install was blocked (if you properly set the `.npmrc` file)